# How do I return one of two types in C?

Tags: c, struct

Suppose this code

```c
typedef struct A {
    ...
} A;

typedef struct B {
    ...
} B;

// If it was TypeScript I would say `type uknown = A | B;`
uknown getAorB(int k) {
    if (k > 0) return (A){...};
    return (B){...};
}
```

That function `getAorB` should return either A or B depending on the parameter `k`. OK, but what is the return type and is it possible to achieve that in C?

Comment: How will the calling function know what was returned?

Comment: Union type perhaps?

Comment: Write two functions, and let the caller decide which to call from what is passed as `k`.

Comment: What is the *actual* underlying problem this is supposed to solve? Why do you need a single function to return different types depending on some variable? Right now this is very much an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please ask about the actual and underlying problem directly, perhaps presenting this as a possible solution you thought about.

Comment: In C, this makes little sense (if it was possible - but it isn't) as you need to use the returned value somehow, for example by storing in a variable. But what type would the variable be ?

Comment: @WeatherVane it's quite easy to do so, but I wanted one function that decides that. If that's impossible to define such a type, I'm gonna switch back to TypeScript. I just wanted some layer of abstraction :n

Comment: @DickWilliams Then you're back to TypeScript or sideways to Python or C++. C doesn't have [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection), which is the feature you need to return different types from the same function.

Comment: It is feasible by returning a `void*` pointer to a `struct` you allocated, but the caller still has to know which type was returned.

Comment: I like [C Object Oriented Programming](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/10/21/) for it's examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unions.

```
typedef struct A {
    ...
} A;

typedef struct B {
    ...
} B;

typedef union
{
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
}A_OR_B;

// If it was TypeScript I would say `type uknown = A | B;`
A_OR_B getAorB(int k) {
    A_OR_B c;
    if (k > 0) c.a.member = something;
        else c.b.member = somethingelse;
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to have another struct which contains the 'type'
of the returned struct. Here is what this may look like:

```
#define STRUCTA 1
#define STRUCTB 2

typedef struct SUPER {
   int type;
} SUPER;    

typedef struct A {
   int type;
   ...
} A;

typedef struct B {
   int type;
   ...
} B;


SUPER* getAorB(int k) {

    if (k > 0) {
        A *a;
        a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
        a->type = STRUCTA;
        return (SUPER*)a;
    } 
    
    B *b;
    b = malloc(sizeof(*b));
    b->type = STRUCTB;
    return (SUPER*)b;
}
```

Then in the calling function you check the type of the SUPER and cast it to the appropriate function.

```
A *a;
B *b;

if (returnedSuper->type == STRUCTA) {
    a = (A*)returnedSuper;
}
else if (returnedSuper->type == STRUCTB) {
    b = (B*)returnedSuper;
}
```

Comment: It is a very inefficient solution (malloc can be seriously costly) + it will add a lot of hassle as you need to **free** the allocated memory when not needed. It also violates the strict aliasing rules. Always be very conscious when you see pointer casts. It is a sign of poor code and potential UBs. IMO it is a quite poor solution because of that.